# R: How to compare values of a single variable when multiple variables are grouped

Tags: r

I have a data set of time depth recordings, from narwhals tagged with two tag types (both recording dive data). I would like to compare the two tag types to determine if they record the same dive depth at the same time stamp, for each whale, but I don't know how to do this.

my data looks like this:

```
library(hms)
diveDummy <- data.frame(tagID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                                  3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                        tagDay = as.Date(c('2017-09-04', '2017-09-04', '2017-09-04', '2017-09-04', '2017-09-04', '2017-09-04',
                                       '2017-09-04', '2017-09-04', '2017-09-04', '2017-09-04', '2017-09-04', '2017-09-04',
                                       '2017-09-05', '2017-09-05', '2017-09-05', '2017-09-05', '2017-09-05',' 2017-09-05'),
                                     '%Y-%m-%d'),
                        tagType = c("mk","mk","mk","mini","mini","mini",
                                    "mk","mk","mk","mini","mini","mini",
                                    "mk","mk","mk","mini","mini","mini"),
                        timeDive = as_hms(c('00:18:45', '00:19:15', '00:19:45', '00:18:45', '00:19:15', '00:19:45',
                                            '00:18:45', '00:19:15', '00:19:45', '00:18:45', '00:19:15', '00:20:15',
                                            '00:18:45', '00:19:15', '00:19:45', '00:18:45', '00:19:15', '00:19:45')),
                        diveDepth = c(0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 1.5,
                                      20, 1, 0.5, 18, 1.5, 0.5,
                                      0, 0.5, 1,0, 0.5, 1.5))
```

Essentially, grouping tagID, tagDay. Then when a whale (tagID) has both types of tags ("mk" and "mini") and the time is identical, then I'd like to compare diveDepth to determine which rows don't match.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
setDT(diveDummy)[, checkmatch := uniqueN(tagType)>1 & uniqueN(diveDepth)==1,.(tagID,tagDay,timeDive)]
```

which gives

```
    tagID     tagDay tagType timeDive diveDepth checkmatch
 1:     1 2017-09-04      mk 00:18:45       0.0       TRUE
 2:     1 2017-09-04      mk 00:19:15       0.5       TRUE
 3:     1 2017-09-04      mk 00:19:45       1.0      FALSE
 4:     1 2017-09-04    mini 00:18:45       0.0       TRUE
 5:     1 2017-09-04    mini 00:19:15       0.5       TRUE
 6:     1 2017-09-04    mini 00:19:45       1.5      FALSE
 7:     2 2017-09-04      mk 00:18:45      20.0      FALSE
 8:     2 2017-09-04      mk 00:19:15       1.0      FALSE
 9:     2 2017-09-04      mk 00:19:45       0.5      FALSE
10:     2 2017-09-04    mini 00:18:45      18.0      FALSE
11:     2 2017-09-04    mini 00:19:15       1.5      FALSE
12:     2 2017-09-04    mini 00:20:15       0.5      FALSE
13:     3 2017-09-05      mk 00:18:45       0.0       TRUE
14:     3 2017-09-05      mk 00:19:15       0.5       TRUE
15:     3 2017-09-05      mk 00:19:45       1.0      FALSE
16:     3 2017-09-05    mini 00:18:45       0.0       TRUE
17:     3 2017-09-05    mini 00:19:15       0.5       TRUE
18:     3 2017-09-05    mini 00:19:45       1.5      FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution @ThomasIsCoding I'm not familiar with that package but I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps a rare occasion where conversion to a "wide" data format assists with inspection of the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

diveDummy %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = tagType, values_from = diveDepth) %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(mini == mk, TRUE, FALSE))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   tagID tagDay     timeDive    mk  mini flag 
   <dbl> <date>     <time>   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1 2017-09-04 18'45"     0     0   TRUE 
 2     1 2017-09-04 19'15"     0.5   0.5 TRUE 
 3     1 2017-09-04 19'45"     1     1.5 FALSE
 4     2 2017-09-04 18'45"    20    18   FALSE
 5     2 2017-09-04 19'15"     1     1.5 FALSE
 6     2 2017-09-04 19'45"     0.5  NA   NA   
 7     2 2017-09-04 20'15"    NA     0.5 NA   
 8     3 2017-09-05 18'45"     0     0   TRUE 
 9     3 2017-09-05 19'15"     0.5   0.5 TRUE 
10     3 2017-09-05 19'45"     1     1.5 FALSE
```

If you want to stay with long data, the approach is very similar to the answer using `data.table`, just with tidyverse syntax:

```
diveDummy %>% 
  group_by(tagID, tagDay, timeDive) %>% 
  mutate(tagTypeCount = n_distinct(tagType),
         flag = ifelse(n_distinct(diveDepth) == 1 & tagTypeCount == 2, TRUE, FALSE))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 7
# Groups:   tagID, tagDay, timeDive [10]
   tagID tagDay     tagType timeDive diveDepth tagTypeCount flag 
   <dbl> <date>     <chr>   <time>       <dbl>        <int> <lgl>
 1     1 2017-09-04 mk      18'45"         0              2 TRUE 
 2     1 2017-09-04 mk      19'15"         0.5            2 TRUE 
 3     1 2017-09-04 mk      19'45"         1              2 FALSE
 4     1 2017-09-04 mini    18'45"         0              2 TRUE 
 5     1 2017-09-04 mini    19'15"         0.5            2 TRUE 
 6     1 2017-09-04 mini    19'45"         1.5            2 FALSE
 7     2 2017-09-04 mk      18'45"        20              2 FALSE
 8     2 2017-09-04 mk      19'15"         1              2 FALSE
 9     2 2017-09-04 mk      19'45"         0.5            1 FALSE
10     2 2017-09-04 mini    18'45"        18              2 FALSE
11     2 2017-09-04 mini    19'15"         1.5            2 FALSE
12     2 2017-09-04 mini    20'15"         0.5            1 FALSE
13     3 2017-09-05 mk      18'45"         0              2 TRUE 
14     3 2017-09-05 mk      19'15"         0.5            2 TRUE 
15     3 2017-09-05 mk      19'45"         1              2 FALSE
16     3 2017-09-05 mini    18'45"         0              2 TRUE 
17     3 2017-09-05 mini    19'15"         0.5            2 TRUE 
18     3 2017-09-05 mini    19'45"         1.5            2 FALSE
```

Comment: It is an interesting output expressed in a wide data.frame, +1!

Comment: I think staying long and grouping is generally the better option. Also not sure if this would work for the real, full dataset. But maybe worth thinking about.

Comment: Thank you very much @neilfws, your solution did work for me. Also thank you for making the edits to my example. I would like to know how to keep it long but I'm not familiar enough with R code to know how to do that, an if else statement?

Comment: Your example data is already "long" (or "tidy"), because every variable has its own column (including `tagType`). I can edit the answer to show how to use that - it is a similar idea to the answer using data.table, just different syntax.